# How do I center the elements inside a div from the below code

Tags: html, css

please take a look at my code at [**JSFIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/dkw6vyau/) , I want to center all the boxes inside a `div`. How do I do it?

[image]

Any Help would be appreciated.

Comment: You question isn't clear.

Comment: I want to center the boxes inside a main div

Comment: Do you mean the header and the tagline?

Comment: please have a look at this screenshot, I want to center the boxes on my page, which is now aligned at the left corner 

http://prntscr.com/6gbiub

Comment: so do you want the boxes in a row, or keep them the same vertically like currently but center them all horizontally?

Comment: @sdcr - Exactly, you got my point.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you meant to **horizontal center** your `.container` , then , you should **not** use the `float` properti but turn them into inline-boxes via `display` with `inline-block` or `inline-table` .
Then apply: `text-align:center` on parent, here `body` or `.grid-main` from your jsfiddle.[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/dkw6vyau/3/)

```css
body {
    text-align:center;
}
legend {
    display: block;
    width: 323px;
    margin: 0 auto 0 auto;
    font-size: 20px;
    font-family: sans-serif;
}
body {
}
.grid-main {
    width: auto;
    margin:auto;
    line-height: 12px;
    overflow: hidden;
    /* border: 1px solid #000; */
}
.grid-sub {
}
.thumb {
    border-top-right-radius: 10px;
    border-top-left-radius: 10px;
    width: 323px;
    height: 160px;
    background-image: url(fashion.jpg);
    background-size: 323px 160px;
}
.clearfix {
    margin: 20px;
}
.container {
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 0px 27px -6px rgba(138, 138, 138, 1);
    -moz-box-shadow: 0px 0px 27px -6px rgba(138, 138, 138, 1);
    box-shadow: 0px 0px 27px -6px rgba(138, 138, 138, 1);
    width: 323px;
    height: auto;
    margin: 10pt;
    border: 1px solid #c0c0c0;
    border-radius: 10px;
    border-top: none;
    display:inline-block;/* NOT FLOAT */
    text-align:left;
}
.top-res-box-overlay {
    background: rgba(0, 0, 0, .3);
    background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0%, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0)), color-stop(1%, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0)), color-stop(100%, rgba(0, 0, 0, .65)));
    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0)0, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0)1%, rgba(0, 0, 0, .65)100%);
    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0)0, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0)1%, rgba(0, 0, 0, .65)100%);
    background: linear-gradient(to bottom, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0)0, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0)1%, rgba(0, 0, 0, .65)100%);
    filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(startColorstr='#00000000', endColorstr='#a6000000', GradientType=0);
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    /*position: relative;
*/
    display: block;
    border-radius: 10px 10px 0 0;
}
div.header {
    position: relative;
    height: 160px;
    width: 323px;
}
.box-name {
    font-size: 13pt;
    display: block;
    color: #fff;
    text-shadow: 0 0 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, .5);
}
.box-name-desc {
    font-size: 10pt;
    display: block;
    color: #fff;
    margin-top: 5px;
    font-weight: 100;
    text-shadow: 0 0 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, .5);
}
div.header div.title {
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0px;
    color: #FFF;
    font-family: sans-serif;
    font-weight: bold;
    padding: 10px;
}
.content {
    width: 100%;
    /*border: 1px solid #c1c1c1;
 border-bottom-left-radius: 10px;
 border-bottom-right-radius: 10px;*/
}
.bottom {
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
}
.context {
    padding: 10px;
    font-size: 13px;
    line-height: 150%;
    color: #9a9a9a;
    font-family: sans-serif;
}
```

```html
<body>
    <div class="grid-main">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="thumb">
                <div class="header"> <a href="#" class="top-res-box-overlay"></a>

                    <div class="title"> <span class="box-name">Header</span>
 <span class="box-name-desc">Tagline</span>

                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="content">
                <div class="context">Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it</div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="container">
            <div class="thumb">
                <div class="header"> <a href="#" class="top-res-box-overlay"></a>

                    <div class="title"> <span class="box-name">Header</span>
 <span class="box-name-desc">Tagline</span>

                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="content">
                <div class="context">Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it</div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="container">
            <div class="thumb">
                <div class="header"> <a href="#" class="top-res-box-overlay"></a>

                    <div class="title"> <span class="box-name">Title</span>
 <span class="box-name-desc">Tagline</span>

                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="content">
                <div class="context">Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it</div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="container">
            <div class="thumb">
                <div class="header"> <a href="#" class="top-res-box-overlay"></a>

                    <div class="title"> <span class="box-name">Title</span>
 <span class="box-name-desc">Tagline</span>

                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="content">
                <div class="context">Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it</div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
```

Comment: `text-align:center` on the parent is not necessary now days I think.

Comment: @sdcr it does on element displayed as inline-boxes , margin auto works only with elements behaving as block elements

Comment: OK didn't pay attention that you suggested OP to convert those blocks into inline-block.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is the float value on `.container`, so do it like this:

```
.container {
    float: left; /* remove this */
    margin: 10pt auto; /* add this */
}
```

If you need to center align a [inline element](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Inline_elemente) (`<span> <b> <i>` ...) or inline-* elements you can add `text-align: center;` to its parent container.

If you need center align a [block element](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Block-level_elements) (`<div> <p>` ...) you can add `margin-left: auto; margin-right: auto;` to the element itself.

Answer (score -1):

If you know the width and height of the "div.title" you can put:

```
div.header div.title {
  left: 50%;
  top: 50%;
  margin-left: -XXpx;
  margin-top: -YYpx;
}
```

Where XX is the half of the width and YY is the half of the height.

Comment: You misunderstood my question, I want to center the boxes, not the titles!